# Remove zeros and calculate the length of the row using python

Tags: python

I had a matrix

```
A = 
[[ 1.         -0.         -0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.11803399  0.38729833 -0.         -0.        ]
 [ 1.22474487  0.70710678 -0.         -0.        ]
 [ 1.32287566  0.98198051  0.         -0.        ]
 [ 0.70710678 -0.40824829  0.57735027  0.        ]
 [ 0.8660254  -0.5         0.70710678  0.40824829]
 [ 1.         -0.57735027  0.81649658  0.70710678]
 [ 0.70710678  0.40824829 -0.57735027 -0.        ]
 [ 0.8660254   0.83333333 -0.47140452 -0.        ]
 [ 1.          1.15470054 -0.40824829 -0.        ]]
```

Then I want to calculate the length of each row after removing zeros
I am using this

```
L_C =  []
for row in A:        
    L_C1 = len(row[row!=0])
    L_C.append(L_C1)
print(L_C)
```

and I am getting lengths like

```
[4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

but they should be

```
[0,1,1,1,2,3,3,2,2,2]
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your posted code is not legal; `A` appears to be some imported type.

Comment: Also, you seem to check whether the row number is zero; I see nothing that checks the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counting only solutions:

- Using Numpy:

```py
import numpy as np
A = [[1,2,3, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]

np.count_nonzero(A, axis=1)
# Output: 
# [3,1]
```

- Built-in packages:

```py
A = [[1,2,3, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]

Output = [sum(x != 0 for x in row) for row in A]
# Output
# [3, 1]
```

Removing 0's and counting:

```py
A = [[1,2,3, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]

A_new = [[x for x in row if x != 0] for row in A]
counts = [len(row) for row in A_new]
# [3, 1]
```

Comment: When I use these for above mentioned matrix I am still getting sam answer like [4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]

Comment: @bhagiradh Can you edit your question and add an example for matrix `A`? Maybe there are some tiny yet non zero values in your input like `-1e-32` that are so tiny and printed as `0`